# OsteoSort R Package cannot access Julia

Tags: r, julia

I am unable to load the OsteoSort package. I am an (extreme) novice in coding and have exhausted all options that I am aware of/capable of understanding. I believe the issue is with Julia (yes, I do have Julia downloaded locally). I have followed the recommendations listed in the box below. I have included the error message received and a screen capture of the loading screen.
[image: Loading Screen]

```
Loading required package: devtools
Loading required package: usethis
> install_github("jjlynch2/OsteoSort", ref="v1.3.1")
Skipping install of 'OsteoSort' from a github remote, the SHA1 (76d19f3d) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
> library(OsteoSort)
Loading required package: pixmap
Loading required package: jpeg
Loading required package: Morpho
Loading required package: DT
Loading required package: shiny

Attaching package: ‘shiny’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:DT’:

    dataTableOutput,
    renderDataTable

Loading required package: htmltools
Loading required package: zip

Attaching package: ‘zip’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:utils’:

    unzip, zip

Loading required package: rgl
Loading required package: JuliaCall
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: shinyalert

Attaching package: ‘shinyalert’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    runExample

Loading required package: networkD3

Attaching package: ‘networkD3’

The following object is masked from ‘package:DT’:

    JS

Loading required package: dplyr

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff,
    setequal, union

Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: network

‘network’ 1.18.1 (2023-01-24), part of the Statnet Project
* ‘news(package="network")’ for changes since last version
* ‘citation("network")’ for citation information
* ‘https://statnet.org’ for help, support, and other information

Loading required package: sna
Loading required package: statnet.common

Attaching package: ‘statnet.common’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    attr, order

sna: Tools for Social Network Analysis
Version 2.7-1 created on 2023-01-24.
copyright (c) 2005, Carter T. Butts, University of California-Irvine
 For citation information, type citation("sna").
 Type help(package="sna") to get started.


Attaching package: ‘sna’

The following object is masked from ‘package:Morpho’:

    symmetrize

> OsteoSort()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5136
Warning: Good news!
You don't need to call `useShinyalert()` anymore. Please remove this line from your code.
If you really want to pre-load {shinyalert} to the UI for any reason, use:
    `useShinyalert(force = TRUE)`
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
Warning: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
Warning: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
The `name` provided ('keyboard-o') does not correspond to a known icon
Warning: Error in julia_setup: Julia is not found.
  49: stop
  48: julia_setup
  47: julia$do.call
  46: julia$call
  45: julia_exists
  44: JuliaSetup
  39: server [C:\Users\kenzd\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\OsteoSort\OsteoSort/server.R#12]
   2: runApp
   1: OsteoSort
Error in julia_setup() : Julia is not found.
```

I followed the recommendations outlines on the following pages. (Unsure whether I followed them correctly - guidance would be appreciated).

https://github.com/jjlynch2/OsteoSort/tree/v1.3.1
https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/

Comment: Hi Kenzie! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like OsteoSort starts correctly, it is just unable to see Julia. Would you be able to open a terminal, enter `julia`, and tell me if anything comes up when you hit enter? Thanks!